# How to output node's ip from each AZ in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, terraform

I am using terraform definitions to launch 10 nodes on AWS in Tokyo region (Two AZ's). So its like 5 nodes are being launched in each AZ.

```
resource "aws_instance" "test" {
  count                   = "${var.dse_cass_node_count}"
  ami                     = "${var.dse_cass_ami}"
  instance_type           = "${var.dse_cass_instance_type}"
  key_name                = "${var.dse_cass_key_name}"
  subnet_id               = "${element(split(",", var.dse_cass_vpc_subnets), count.index)}"
  availability_zone       = "${element(split(",", var.dse_cass_azs), count.index)}"
  vpc_security_group_ids  = ["${var.dse_sg_id}"]

  tags {
    Name             = "${var.namespace}-${var.env_name}-${var.dse_cluster_name}-node-${count.index}"
    Environment      = "${var.env_name}"
    DSE_Cluster_Name = "${var.dse_cluster_name}"
  }
}
```

I want to have node's IP based on AZ in output. Right now I can list all node's ip's in output using definitions mentioned below but not able to get based on AZ.

```
output "cassandra_ips" {
  value = ["${aws_instance.test.*.private_ip}"]
}

output "cassandra_ips1" {
  value = ["${aws_instance.test.0.private_ip}"]
}

output "cassandra_ips2" {
  value = ["${aws_instance.test.1.private_ip}"]
}
```

I want to segregate them based on AZ's. Is it possible using Terraform? I would like to have one node's ip from each AZ.
It would be great to have some suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Terraform v0.10.5

P.S - I want one node's ip from each AZ to add in Cassandra's seed list.

Answer (score 1):

Terraform allows for outputs of maps. Syntax would be something like this, I have not tried this out.

> value (required) - The value of the output. This can be a string,
>   list, or **map**. This usually includes an interpolation since outputs
>   that are static aren't usually useful.

```
output "cassandra_ip_map" {
  value = {
  "${aws_instance.test.*.availability_zone}" = "${aws_instance.test.*.private_ip}"  
  }
}
```

https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/outputs.html

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/instance.html#availability_zone

Comment: Can it make terraform crash by any chance? Terraform is crashing after I add above lines in output. 


panic: reflect.Value.SetMapIndex: value of type []interface {} is not assignable to type string

Comment: It's likely, try reading the log, "You can set TF_LOG to one of the log levels TRACE, DEBUG, INFO, WARN or ERROR to change the verbosity of the logs. TRACE is the most verbose and it is the default if TF_LOG is set to something other than a log level name." https://www.terraform.io/docs/internals/debugging.html

Comment: Can you post a link to the full terraform?

Comment: Terraform definitions are huge with number of modules and private keys with passwords. So won't be able to share the entire definitions. How can I attach the entire logs here?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Nahushp/70cd52a10348bceb2c03a0f39e80ede1

Well 'test' resource name is question is 'cassandra_ebs' resource name in actual definition

Comment: This looks like a new error on the EBS volume creation?

Comment: I think the log on cassandra_volumn is just INFO and not an error - Terraform plan crashes only if I use "cassandra_ip_map" in outputs.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out a working solution based on previous comment

```
output "cassandra_ip_zmap" {
  value = "${
    zipmap(
      "${aws_instance.test.*.availability_zone}", "${aws_instance.test.*.private_ip}"
    )
  }"
}
```